# How To update values in a specific row and column in access using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub btnUpdateu3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateu3.Click
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into ecd (first_name, last_name, relationship, phone_number)" + "Values('" + txtefnu3.Text + "','" + txtelnu3.Text + "','" + txterelu3.Text + "', '" + txtecnu3.Text + "')" + "Where student_id('" + txtsidu3.Text + "');"
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Insertion Successful")

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add a description. Just some code under the question is not making any sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you require an Update query, not an Insert.

```
Private Sub btnUpdateu3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateu3.Click
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "UPDATE ecd SET first_name = '" + txtefnu3.Text + "', last_name = '" + txtelnu3.Text + "', relationship = '" + txterelu3.Text + "', phone_number = '" + txtecnu3.Text + "' WHERE student_id = '" + txtsidu3.Text + "';"
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Insertion Successful")
End Sub
```

That assumes a non-numerical student id (per your original). If the student id field is numeric then you shouldn't have wrapping single quotes (e.g. `'` ).

Comment: Please use parameters. I don't see the connection being opened. If it is opened somewhere else and left flapping in the breeze, that is even worse. I would hope that student_id is a number even though the OP presents it as a string. Love the dog!